# What is the difference between Backoffice and Cockpit frameworks?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Recently i've started learning hybris and come across these two terms.I feel both are same because they both are related to User Interface.

somebody please  help me understand how **backoffice** and **cockpit** are different.

Answer (score 1):

Since Hybris 6, Backoffice is the new more generic UI for managing your Hybris Store. This is the successor of HMC. (Hybris Management Console) Cockpits will become deprecated in a few versions. Using them, you have to handle several different extensions (Product Cockpit, Customer Service Cockpit, CMS Cockpit etc..), which use different frameworks and styles.

The main idea of having different cockpits is to separate different dedicated teams and concerns. Also they have some customizations, which are much more usable, than HMC. With Backoffice, you can create the same functionality with different modules.

In general, if you start a new shop, i would recommend using the Backoffice. This is the new way to administrate you shop.

Comment: Why do we still use cockpits when we have backoffice.? Is it not possible to completely eliminate HMC and cockpits yet?

Comment: Depends on the project. HMC can be easily migrated to Backoffice. There is even a tool, which migrates your HMC configuration to Backoffice. The reasons why cockpits are still used: Old projects, where customers are used the old interface and migrating customization to backoffice will take a lot of effort. Also some cockpits still provide OOB functionality, which has to be configured in Backoffice.

Answer (score 0):

**backoffice** is a new framework which is a replacement for old **cockpits**.

**backoffice** advantages:

- the new architecture allows developer to focus and spend more time on important things (application logic) instead of all secondary tasks (e.g. security - authentication and authorization, notifications etc.)
- it offers a lot of standard reusable components so you can create new applications faster (from ready blocks):

  - actions: create, delete, search etc.
  - editors: decimal editor, text editor, reference editor etc.
  - widgets: collection browser, border layout, explorer tree etc.
- your applications will be more consistent and intuitive, because they use the same components
- it groups applications in one place, so the client does not need to know many URLs (he can open one application and everything will be in one place)